# cannot authenticate r shinyapps account with rsconnect

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

Trying to install reconnect and authenticate it with R-shiny. However, it seems unable to find the function file size.

Here is the installation:

```
> install.packages("rsconnect", type = "source", dependencies = TRUE, repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/")
Installing package into ‘/Users/~/Library/R/3.1/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rsconnect_0.8.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 245177 bytes (239 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 239 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘rsconnect’ ...
** package ‘rsconnect’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (rsconnect)
```

The downloaded source packages are in

```
/private/VAb/downloaded_packages
```

Here is the error when I try to register my account.

```
rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='me',
+                           token='token',
+                           secret='pass')
Error in inferCertificateContents(system.file("cert/shinyapps.io.pem",  : 
  could not find function "file.size"
```